# Why I cannot access the C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC Folder?

Tags: c#, reference, gac, .net-assembly

I find the path of Microsoft.Office>interop.Excel under the Solution/References is

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\11.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

However, such a file doesn't exist on my C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC at all. Further, there is not GAC folder under C:\WINDOWS\assembly.

Any idea?

Comment: @ibram, it seems to me that this library is used for operating Excel.

Comment: If you need to reference it in your app, you can add it through the "add reference" in your project. Additional you can set the reference with copylocal=true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the command prompt to navigate there.  Windows Explorer has an extension that runs for the assembly folder, hiding some of the details.

Here is a post on how to turn it off.  http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2006/05/05/WindowsExplorerAndTheGlobalAssemblyCache.aspx
or 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jkey/archive/2003/02/25/3006.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It is propably easiest to type to following in Start->Run: %windir%\assembly\gac

Some people use the [subst command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst) to map a drive letter to the GAC: SUBST [Drive letter]: “C:\Windows\assembly”

Personally I would get a hold of the Office Primary Interop Assemblies [(Here is the PIA for 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855), they should contain the assembly you need

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable the GAC shell extension -

run regedit - navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion` 
create `DisableCacheViewer` DWORD - set the value to `0x1`.

After this open the assembly folder and you should see the sub folders and navigate into them.

But if you want to copy the assemblies from them -I'm not sure why?
In you case you want Excel PIA's. All the Office versions also provide PIAs

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&displaylang=en) are the PIA's for Office 2007.